# An integral question which i have never encountered before

Tags: calculus, integration

I = $\int _{0}^{3}\left( 1+x^{2}\right) d[ x]$

$a)12$

$b)17$

$c)15$

$d)19$

where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$,

shouldn't this integral be $0$ since $d[x]$ is 0 for all $x$ in the domain of the function.
what is the correct explanation ??

Comment: Can we not use $\int f(x)dg(x)=\int f(x) g’(x)dx$?

Answer (score 2):

This is the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of $(1+x^2)$ from $0$ to $3$ with respect to $g(x)=[x]$.

This integral can be evaluated like a Riemann sum, partitioning $[0,3]$ into intervals with tags and increasing the number of intervals. The kind of sum we're trying to evaluate is:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\>|g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})| $$

Here, we'll use the rightmost point as the tag for definiteness, but it doesn't change the answer. Notice that the function $g$ is constant in each of the open intervals $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, and $(2,3)$, so the factors on the right are only nonzero when we evaluate $g$ on two different intervals: when $x_i=1,2,3$. The sum then reduces to:

$$ f(1) + f(2) + f(3) = 2 + 5 + 10 = 17$$

Another way to think about this is, as the comments suggest, using the definition $\int f(x)dg(x)=\int f(x) g’(x)dx$. Here, we need $g$ to be differentiable, but if we allow some hand-wavy use of the delta function then $g'(x) = \delta(x-1) + \delta(x-2) + \delta(x-3) $ which also gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you think integration as sum of areas of rectangles under the function, it will be easy. Like breadth of rectangles generally is $dx$ $\to  $ $0$ but here $d[x]$ is I think equals to $1$. So make rectangles of breadth $1$.
[image]

Answer will be sum of all

$\sum f(x)d[x]$ that is

.$ f(0)d[x] + f(0+d[x])d[x] + f(0+2d[x])d[x]$.

So answer becomes
$2×1 + 5×1 + 10×1 = 17$

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I dont believe your solution is correct. from 0 to 1 dx = 0 so area of that rectangle is 0. From 1 to 2 dx = 1 and f(x) changes from 2 to 5. From 2 to 3 dx = 2 and f(x) changes from 5 to 10